# Anchor download link not working in IE and Firefox

Tags: html

In my website, I want to give download option for user,so I have added download attribute in the anchor tag which is not working on IE and Firefox.I meant,Instead of showing a save dialog it is opening a new tab.

```
<a href="http:\\www.website-2.com" download="elam.txt"></a>
```

I am mentioning the path which is pointing document server(www.website-2.com).

For testing purpose I have mentioned local path(/images/fist.pdf) which is pointing my local resources and it is downloading.

I think download attribute will not support to download the different website resources.

Comment: read here http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/markup/using-the-html5-download-attribute.html maybe help

Comment: I gone through the link,it seems they were used JQuery.I do not want to use JQuery. I want to implement with help of HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

download is a boolean attribute. So it not need any url, anchors href value will be download. But it is not supported in ie and ff < 20. You can check this here : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: MDN link instead of W3Schools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Comment: what is the alternate for this problem?

Comment: `filename` - `Optional. Specifies the new filename for the downloaded file` you post link without read it

Comment: I gave the file name like the belllow:<a href="http:\\www.website-2.com\elam.txt" download="elam.txt"></a>
still it is not working

Comment: I will not use 2 events in same link. Like downloading file through download attribute and sending in another page with href attribute. So it is better to use href to set the download. And no need to enter same url 2 times, 1 in href and another in download.

Comment: You should check console error, if it is missing due to path or name problem.

Comment: I have used now :
<a href="" download="http:\\www.website-2.com\elam.txt">Download</a> 
It is downloading,but I am unable to open the file.it is saying file got corrupted.